# WordPress is Truncating the Slug, and the truncated slug is being Indexed by the SE

Tags: php, wordpress, slug

My site is having a problem which seems a WP bug. Some post slugs are being truncated and getting indexed as the truncated url. The search engine is seeing both the original URL and the truncated URL. It does not happen for all time but eventually.

You can understand the problem from this screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIaAx.png. Please help!

Comment: Search engines don't update their indexes the second you change your URLs. You've already got a 301 redirect on http://www.oxhow.com/install- to http://www.oxhow.com/install-adobe-reader-on-linux-distros/, so all you need to do is wait until Google removes the incorrect link from their index. This can take months.

Comment: Exactly. But I want to stop WP from generating such unwanted urls which I never created.

Comment: But this "bug" doesn't affect the majority of Wordpress users, so it's not like there's a piece of code we can provide that will magically fix all your problems (otherwise, Wordpress would have already been patched). There a 99.99% chance that this issue is happening due to a corrupted installation, some obscure code in your theme, a plugin trying to do something with your permalinks, or a combination of the above which causes Wordpress to generate incomplete permalinks. Reinstall the latest version of Wordpress, disable & check all your plugins, and check your theme, then report back.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, create an account in **[Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/)** and submit your site. This has many features, one of them being able to view the list of crawl errors such as broken links etc.

Another option in it is, if you have changed a URL, you can tell google to manually crawl it again in **[here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?)** so that it displays the updated link in the SE (although there is no mention of the expected update time).

Comment: @ I Can Has Cheezburger: That is not my problem. I publish posts from my WP dashboard and never edit the slug. Now I published that post from the WP dashboard as usual. Which should apear as mysite[dot]com/permanent-blah-blah-slag/ . 

The problem is that another link is automatically being generated like this mysite[dot]com/permanent-

and this is my problem. WP should not generate such urls which I never created.

Comment: @Tanmay I haven't worked with wordpress but are you using any sort of plugin that optimizes your slug? They may contain stop words or limit the number of slugs.

Comment: I am using WordPress SEO by Yoast which provides the facility to optimize slugs but I am not using this feature.